# Word VBA: Need to remove frames but maintain formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

I currently have a word document formatted in columns and rows like such (it is about 100 rows and 6 columns in the real example):

```
  a  b  c  d  
1 x  x  x  x 
2 x  x  x  x
3 x  x  x  x
4 x  x  x  x
```

Everything has a separate frame, i.e. there are 24 frames in this example. However, when I remove any frame, the formatting does not remain the same (the text tends to go to the top left of the word document).

The reason this is an issue is because I cannot add to the document by typing due to the 'frame formatting' .

I converted the document from xps to docx.

I tried this VBA code which did remove the frames but did not keep the formatting.

```
Sub CleanUpExport()
Dim aFrame As Frame
Dim p As Paragraph
Dim l As Single

For Each aFrame In ActiveDocument.Frames
   aFrame.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
   l = aFrame.HorizontalPosition
   For  each p In aFrame.Range.Paragraphs
      p.LeftIndent = l
   Next p
   aFrame.Delete
Next aFrame
End Sub
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the content of the frame before deleting the frame and then paste in the same location, you should get the same formatting as before

Comment: There are 1500 words and also approx 1500 frames, this wouldn't be practical. I tried copying the whole document and using the various paste special options, but none worked. Some removed the frames, but none (except the picture options) kept the formatting. But I cannot choose the picture option since I need to edit the document afterwards.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem perfectly, but I imagine that your snippet can be adjusted to go frame by frame and replace them with their content via cut and paste